# comparing data from first quarter in two years

Tags: data-mining, visualization, data-analysis, tableau, powerbi

How can I compare data from two quarters? What software can I use to do it parallelly side by side so I can compare them. What kind of factors can I take into consideration, I'm posting a sample data set pic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what output you are looking for.

There are many ways to do it. You can do it by creating a measure in Power BI or in PowerPivot or just using Powerquery - below is an example.

PowerPivot and PowerQuery can both put the output into a pivot table in Excel if that's something you prefer.

```
Pick up city    Q1       Q2    
X              Amount1   Amount 2    
Y              ...       ...
```